# Arraylist output getting overriden

Tags: java, arraylist

The data which was previously stored in an array list , is getting replaced by updated data.

code is shown below

```java
public class Telivision {

    private String tvBrand;
    private Double tvCost;
    private Integer tvDimension;
    private String tvScreen;
    public String getTvBrand() {
        return tvBrand;
    }
    public void setTvBrand(String tvBrand) {
        this.tvBrand = tvBrand;
    }
    public Double getTvCost() {

        return tvCost;
    }
    public void setTvCost(String brand) {
        if(this.tvBrand.equalsIgnoreCase("Samsung")){
            this.tvCost = 100*1.5;
        }else if(this.tvBrand.equalsIgnoreCase("Sony")){
            this.tvCost = 100*2.0;
        }
    }
    public Integer getTvDimension() {
        return tvDimension;
    }
    public void setTvDimension(Integer tvDimension) {
        this.tvDimension = tvDimension;
    }
    public String getTvScreen() {
        return tvScreen;
    }
    public void setTvScreen(String tvScreen) {
        this.tvScreen = tvScreen;
    }
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Telivision [tvBrand=" + tvBrand + ", tvCost=" + tvCost + ", tvDimension=" + tvDimension + ", tvScreen="
                + tvScreen + "]";
    }
```

TESTER IS AS SHOWN BELOW

```java
public class TelivisionTester {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Telivision telivision = new Telivision();
        ArrayList<Telivision> telList = new ArrayList<Telivision>();        
        telivision.setTvBrand("SAMSUNG");
        telivision.setTvDimension(40);
        telivision.setTvScreen("Led");
        telivision.setTvCost("Samsung");
        telList.add(telivision);
        System.out.println(telList);
        System.out.println(telivision.getTvBrand()+"Cost is "+telivision.getTvCost());

        telivision.setTvBrand("Sony");
        telivision.setTvDimension(36);
        telivision.setTvScreen("Led");
        telivision.setTvCost("Sony");
        telList.add(telivision);
        System.out.println(telList);
        System.out.println(telivision.getTvBrand()+"Cost is "+telivision.getTvCost());
    }
```

the output which is expected is as shown below

```
[Telivision [tvBrand=SAMSUNG, tvCost=150.0, tvDimension=40, tvScreen=Led],
Telivision [tvBrand=Sony, tvCost=200.0, tvDimension=36, tvScreen=Led]]
```

but the output observed is as shown below

```
[Telivision [tvBrand=Sony, tvCost=200.0, tvDimension=36, tvScreen=Led], 
Telivision [tvBrand=Sony, tvCost=200.0, tvDimension=36, tvScreen=Led]]
```

kindly let me know what mistake i am doing in this code

Comment: You are not creating a second Telivision. You keep using the first (and only) instance.

Comment: Yeah as f1sh said you are only making 1 television.  Say you have 1 TV in real life and modify it to be different, you still have only 1 TV.  Call `telivision = new Telivision();` again in your test code before the `Sony` brand.

Comment: So in the above code whenever i need to update a new value , i need to create a new object and then update it.

Comment: instanciate 2 Telivisions. `Telivision samsung = new Telivision();` for Samsung and `Telivision sony = new Telivision();` for Sony

Answer (score 0):

You're list is not being overwritten. You are are adding the same instance of the class twice instead of creating a new one with the new attributes.  Because the original istance changed you get the same attributes for both entries in the list.  Create a new instance of the object for each Television you add to the list.

```
   public static void main(String[] args) {

    Telivision telivision = new Telivision();
    ArrayList<Telivision> telList = new ArrayList<Telivision>();        
    telivision.setTvBrand("SAMSUNG");
    telivision.setTvDimension(40);
    telivision.setTvScreen("Led");
    telivision.setTvCost("Samsung");
    telList.add(telivision);
    System.out.println(telList);
    System.out.println(telivision.getTvBrand()+"Cost is "+telivision.getTvCost());
    Telivision secondTelivision = new Telivision();
    secondTelivision.setTvBrand("Sony");
    secondTelivision.setTvDimension(36);
    secondTelivision.setTvScreen("Led");
    secondTelivision.setTvCost("Sony");
    telList.add(secondTelivision);
    System.out.println(telList);


}
```

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to declare a second Telivision to separate the two.

```
public class TelivisionTester {
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Telivision telivision = new Telivision();
    ArrayList<Telivision> telList = new ArrayList<Telivision>();        
    telivision.setTvBrand("SAMSUNG");
    telivision.setTvDimension(40);
    telivision.setTvScreen("Led");
    telivision.setTvCost("Samsung");
    telList.add(telivision);
    System.out.println(telList);
    System.out.println(telivision.getTvBrand()+"Cost is "+telivision.getTvCost());

    Telivision television2 = new Television();
    telivision2.setTvBrand("Sony");
    telivision2.setTvDimension(36);
    telivision2.setTvScreen("Led");
    telivision2.setTvCost("Sony");
    telList.add(telivision2);
    System.out.println(telList);
    System.out.println(telivision2.getTvBrand()+"Cost is "+telivision2.getTvCost());
    //telList.addAll(telList);

    //System.out.println(telList);

}
}
```

Also “Telivision” is actually spelled Television